# Less css compilation puts command itself on first line

Tags: css, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm with set LESS file watcher. Problem is that, when compiling, it adds command itself to beggining of file (you can see it in screenshot, in right column). How to remove it?

---

EDIT:
Compiler is working as it should. When I use same command from cmd, it returns everything as it should (without that line containing command). That means that problem is on PhpStorm side.

[image: setup] 
[image: screen]

Comment: is the command line appended alweays, or in some certain cases only? Please remove the .css file and re-generate - does the problem persist? Also, do you have any other watchers configuraed? Are you sure this watcher is the only one that modifies your css?

Comment: Please attach screenshot of the generated css plus a screenshot of lessc output when running it for the same scss in the command line (what about redirecting its oputput to file to see what ios generated?). As all the watcher does is reading stdout produced by lessc, it doesn't write anything there itself

Comment: @lena I don't have any other watchers configured. Regenerating css file doesn't help. That problem appears everytime PhpStorm compiles that less file (through node and lessc, of course). It doesn't happed when using cmd directly.

Comment: so, the issue is specific to certain file, is it? Can you provide the file that shows it up?